# Inner shadow for a layout

Tags: android

I want to add inner shadow at the top of a layout.I am inflating this layout into a list view.What I want is to show this inner shadow when an item is pressed.?

Comment: anila please elaborate what you want ?? inner shadow means top and end of listview scroll with shadow??